# User Permissions: Shouldn't be able to edit pages, but add/update/delete documents

Tags: 2013, permissions

I want members to be able to add/edit/delete documents, but don't want them to be able to edit the pages itself.

When I set the permission level to Read, they can't edit the pages, but they can't add/edit/delete documents either. When I set the permission level to Contribute, they can both edit the pages & add/edit/delete documents.

Is there a way to set these permissions in a way that I can accomplish what I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two options here (although I'm less sure about whether the second option will work):

1. You can set unique permissions on the document library so that it no longer inherits permissions from its parent site. To do this you would go to document library > library settings > permissions for this document library > stop inheriting permissions. Then you can set different permissions than to the site.
2. You can create a new permission level that allows editing of "items" but not of site pages. Go to site settings > site permissions > permission levels > add permission level, then check "edit items" but uncheck "add and customize pages" (you'll need to check other items as well to give users a decent level of permissions on the site, or you can copy permission levels from an existing permission level). Then assign this new permission level to a group or user.

Answer (score 0):

You can go and make a copy of the Contribute permission level and the remove the `Edit Items` permission.

See [Configure custom permissions in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263239.aspx)

To specify the special permission level at the Pages library see SharePoint 2013: [Break Document Library Permissions Inheritance](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18203.sharepoint-2013-break-document-library-permissions-inheritance.aspx)

Comment: But if you remove the `Edit Items` permission won't that also prevent users from editing documents?

Comment: Yes. You have to break inheritance on either pages or documents.

Comment: How do you break the inheritance to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

```
http://yoursharepointwebsite/_layouts/15/editrole.aspx?role=Contribute
```

But if you uncheck the Edit Items permission, your users will not be able to edit any items or documents. So this doesn't fit your requerement.
But htere are no other option to do that OTB, as

> **Edit Items**  -  Edit items in lists, edit documents in document libraries, and customize Web Part Pages in document libraries.

Comment: If it is not possible OTB, what would be the way to go?